# Compare fetched data with existing data in database, inserting only new items (categories) & deleting missing items

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, android-room

After a while of successfully process in my app, I got to a new problem. It seems not that difficult but I am having trouble to solve it. So, the user adds an account in the AddAccountFragment, the account is an url, and a code - added in 2 edittext-fields. When clicking on the save button in that fragment there are some api calls made (getToken to retrieve a token, that is then passed to other api calls, that fetch different categories, for example getMovieCategory fetches, surprise -> different movie categories). These categories are then inserted in the room database (and it own Entity "MovieCategory". Following the code i use for it in the viewmodel:

```
fun getMovieCategory(url: String, code: String) {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                val token = sessionManager.fetchAuthToken()
                val response = myRepository.getMovieCategory(url, code, "Bearer $token")
                when (response) {
                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        val categories = response.data.js.map { moviecatresponse ->
                            MovieCategory(
                                moviecatresponse.id,
                                moviecatresponse.title,
                                accountData = "$url$code",
                                favorite = false,
                                idByAccountData = "${moviecatresponse.id}$url$code"
                            )
                        }
                        if (categories.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                            println("ERROR MOVIES")
                        } else {
                            dao.insertMovieCategory(categories)
                            _getMovieCategoryLiveData.value = Resource.Success(categories)
                        }
                    }
                    is Resource.Error -> {
                        _getMovieCategoryLiveData.value = Resource.Error(response.message)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

I am using the map method to handle the response of the api-call and to be able to pass it to the room-entity.
In the categorymanagefragement the user has the possibility to modify the favorite status/property of a category (specific button click opens a recyclerview with checkboxes, where the user can click a checkbox to set favorite = true). And in the same fragment the user should have the possibility to "update" the categories-list, or better, check if there are new categories available, or exisiting categories were deleted). For that the api-calls are made a second (or more) time. And there emerges the problem.
When I use:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insertMovieCategory(moviecategory: List<MovieCategory>)
```

I tought that the categories, whose primary keys already exist, are ignored and only categories whose primary keys are "new" are additionally inserted to the existing list. But instead, all categories that were fetched on the second api calls were inserted, also if the primarykey was already there, and logically in that case, the favorite status of each category was set to false again. So basically it was handled as there weren't any primary keys existable.
I am not sure were the cause of the problem lies, maybe it's the map method I use?
Probably I have some logic error I don't recognize. I tought about trying to fetch the existing categories with and compare it with the fetched data. Precisally compare the idByAccountData of the existing categories and the fetched categories, and filter out the Categories, whose idByAccountData already exist, inserting only the other categories into the database. But somehow it didn't seemed to work.

But probably there is a much more easier way, that hopefully someone here can help me to find.
(and mabye the way is the same for deleting categories, whose idByAccountData doesnt exist anymore in the fetched data).

Answer (score 0):

following code solved my problem:

```
 fun getTvCategory(url: String, code: String) {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                val token = sessionManager.fetchAuthToken()
                val response = myRepository.getTvCategory(url, code, "Bearer $token")
                when (response) {
                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        val categories = response.data.js.map { tvcatresponse ->
                            TvCategory(
                                tvcatresponse.id,
                                tvcatresponse.number,
                                tvcatresponse.title,
                                accountData = "$url$macAddress",
                                favorite = false,
                                idByAccountData = "${tvcatresponse.id}$url$code"
                            )
                        }
                        val existingCategories = myRepository.getTvCategoriesPerAccount("$url$code")
                        val newCategories = categories.filter { category ->
                            existingCategories.value?.any { it.idByAccountData == category.idByAccountData } != true
                        }
                        val categoriesToDelete = existingCategories.value?.filter { category ->
                            !categories.any { it.idByAccountData == category.idByAccountData }
                        } ?: emptyList()
                            dao.insertTvCategory(newCategories)
                            categoriesToDelete.forEach {
                                dao.deleteTvCategory(it)
                            }
                        val mergedCategories = existingCategories.value?.plus(newCategories) ?: newCategories
                        _getTvCategoryLiveData.value = Resource.Success(mergedCategories)
                            setTvCategoryRequestSuccessful()
                        }
                    is Resource.Error -> {
                        _getTvCategoryLiveData.value = Resource.Error(response.message)
                        setTvCategoryRequestFailed()
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

additionally in my getToken function I had the method to add the account to the database. So everytime i clicked an account in the categorymanagefragment the account was added newly and everything was set to "null". So i made a second getToken function without the insert method of the account, calling the new getToken function from the fragment. Now everything seems to work correctly